# Need help tuning Mysql and linux server

Tags: mysql, performance-tuning, database-performance

We have multi-user application (like MailChimp,Constant Contact) .
Each of our customers has it's own contact's list (from 5 to 100.000 contacts).
Everything is stored in one BIG database (currently 25G).
Since we released our product we have the following data history.

5 years of data history :
- users/customers (200+)
- contacts (40 million records)
- campaigns 
- campaign_deliveries (73.843.764 records)
- campaign_queue ( 8 millions currently )

As we get more users and table records increase our system/web app is getting slower and slower .
Some queries takes too long to execute .

## SCHEMA

Table contacts

```
--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| contact_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| client_id           | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| name                | varchar(60)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| mail                | varchar(60)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| verified            | int(1)           | YES  |     | 0       |                | 
| owner               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                | 
| date_created        | date             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |  
| geolocation         | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| ip                  | varchar(20)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `owner` (`owner`,`mail`),
  KEY `contacts_index_mail` (`mail`),
  KEY `index_contacts_date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `index_contacts_ip` (`ip`),
```

Table campaign_deliveries

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| newsletter_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                | 
| contact_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                | 
| sent_date     | date             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| sent_time     | time             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| smtp_server   | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| owner         | int(5)           | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| ip            | varchar(20)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
INDEXES
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newsletter_id` (`newsletter_id`,`contact_id`),
  KEY `newsletter_delivery_FKIndex1` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `newsletter_delivery_FKIndex2` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `newsletter_delivery_owner` (`owner`),
  KEY `index_nd_sent_date` (`sent_date`),
  KEY `index_nd_sent_time` (`sent_time`),
  KEY `index_ip` (`ip`)
```

Table campaign_queue

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| queue_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| newsletter_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                | 
| owner         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                | 
| date_to_send  | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| contact_id    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| date_created  | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
INDEXES
PRIMARY KEY  (`queue_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newsletter_id` (`newsletter_id`,`contact_id`),
  KEY `newsletter_queue_index1` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `newsletter_queue_index4` (`owner`),
  KEY `newsletter_queue_index5` (`newsletter_id`),
  KEY `contacts_contact_id` (`contact_id`)
```

Slow queries LOG --------------------------------------------

## Query_time: 350  Lock_time: 1  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 971004

SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `contacts` WHERE (`contacts`.`owner` = 70 AND `contacts`.`verified` = 1);

## Query_time: 235  Lock_time: 1  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 4455209

SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `contacts` WHERE (`contacts`.`owner` = 2);

## EXPLAIN

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `contacts` WHERE (`contacts`.`owner` = 112 AND `contacts`.`verified` = 1);

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contacts | ref  | owner         | owner | 4       | const | 644817 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

---

How can we optimize it ?
Queries should take no more than 30 secs to execute?
Can we optimize it and keep all data in one BIG database or should we change app's structure and set one single database to each user ?

EDIT
table indexes added below schema

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What indexes do you have? You should have an index on contacts.owner, in which case the query should be pretty fast. [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html)

Also, providing the query plan would be useful. [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html)

Comment: I 've just added the indexes ... and I did realize we are missing index for column  "verified" on contacts's table. It should be there, maybe we droped it somehow.

Comment: @Newtonx - Adding an index on verified likely won't be very useful for these queries. MySQL can only use a single index per table, in this case the `owner` index is likely much better.

You could add an index on (owner, verified) but that would likely only be of use if there are lots of records for a owner and mostly un-verified. 

Can you provide EXPLAIN output for this query?

Comment: EXPLAIN added. Please check

Comment: Well, it is using the `owner` index as it should. Is that really returning 644817 rows? If its really in that general ballpark, you might want to add that `(owner, verified)` index, especially if this is a common query. That should make this query fly.

Comment: I currently adding index (owner, verified) to contacts's table.
My server is a Intel Dual Xeon 3210 Quad Core 12G RAM . 
Do you think MySQL can handle this large database ?

Comment: Certainly. 25GB isn't very big at all. The challenge here is that your query simply requires a ton of data. If the index doesn't get you where you need to be, next stop would be to precalculate the data IMO.

Comment: ALter table is running for more then 48 hours now. And I don't think killing the process would be safe. I should had changed my.cnf before running the command.

ALTER TABLE contacts ADD INDEX `contacts_owner_verified_index` (`owner`,`verified`);

Comment: #show processlist;

| 18088 | root             | localhost | inboxmai_newx    | Query   | 126436 | Repair with keycache | ALTER TABLE contacts ADD INDEX `contacts_owner_verified_index` (`owner`,`verified`)